# Reading in data and exceptions

Tags: java, exception

So I need this to read in data from a file and then play a tone on the finch after receiving two integers. In the file there are some integers that have letters in the them like 75K and i would like to skip over that and trash the other integer in the pair. I don't think i fully understand exceptions yet can someone show me? Here is the code(I put in a println so i can see what is happening):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Finch finch = new Finch();
        int dur, freq;
        Scanner inputStream = null;
        String trash;

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner(new File("F:\\Java\\NetbeansFinchFolder\\SourceFiles\\Code\\Lab5Data.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("invalid input");
        } 
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {

            if (inputStream.hasNextInt()) {
                dur = inputStream.nextInt();
                freq = inputStream.nextInt();
                System.out.println(dur);
                System.out.println(freq);
                if (dur > -1 && freq > -1) {
                    finch.setLED(Color.GREEN);
                    finch.playTone(freq, dur);

                }

            } else if(!(inputStream.hasNextInt()))
            {
                finch.setLED(Color.RED, 1000);
                trash = inputStream.next();
                trash = inputStream.next();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Connecting to Finch...this may take a few seconds...
262
500
262
500
262
500
294
250
330
500
330
250
294
250
330
250
349
250
392
500
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at Code.LabAssign5.main(LabAssign5.java:34)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Comment: Just a little note: to confirm which data you're looking at, add the variable name in the println: `System.out.println("dur = " + dur);`

Comment: What would you like us to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to catch exception and handle it somehow:

```
if( inputStream.hasNextInt() )
{
    try
    {
        dur = inputStream.nextInt();
        freq = inputStream.nextInt();
        System.out.println( dur );
        System.out.println( freq );
        if( dur > -1 && freq > -1 )
        {
            finch.setLED( Color.GREEN );
            finch.playTone( freq, dur );
        }
    }
    catch( InputMismatchException exception )
    {
        // do exception handling
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped me out a lot. Im still throwing another exception but it isn't until the end of the file when the one line is just letters. I should be able to figure that one out on my own though

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting this exception here :

```
if (inputStream.hasNextInt()) {
  dur = inputStream.nextInt();
  freq = inputStream.nextInt(); //Here, you did not check that freq is an int.
```

As says the javadoc, a MismatchException is thrown in case you try to get the "nextInt()" when it is not an int :

```
/**
 * Scans the next token of the input as an <tt>int</tt>.
 *
 * <p> An invocation of this method of the form
 * <tt>nextInt()</tt> behaves in exactly the same way as the
 * invocation <tt>nextInt(radix)</tt>, where <code>radix</code>
 * is the default radix of this scanner.
 *
 * @return the <tt>int</tt> scanned from the input
 * @throws InputMismatchException
 *         if the next token does not match the <i>Integer</i>
 *         regular expression, or is out of range
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if input is exhausted
 * @throws IllegalStateException if this scanner is closed
 */
public int nextInt() {
    return nextInt(defaultRadix);
}
```

In your case, `75K` is not an int and you have to parse it manually.

Some hints :

- Use `String.split(String regex)` with a good separator
- Use a `Matcher` with the appropriate regex.

Here is an example with a `Matcher` on `\d` (digits) :

```
String s = "75K 28m";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output :

```
75
28
```

And another example which shows how to split the String on non-digits (`\\D`):

```
String s = "75K 28m";
String[] result = s.split("\D+");
System.out.println(result[0]);
System.out.println(result[1]);
```

Output :

```
75
28
```